failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./gradlew dependencies --no-daemon" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
I have created a Kotlin application in IntelliJ with the following settings:

Name: ktdocker
Build System: Gradle
JDK: corretto-20
Gradle DSL: Kotlin
GroupID: com.demo

When I try to containerize this appliaction to Docker I get the following error:
 => ERROR [builder  9/11] RUN ./gradlew dependencies --no-daemon
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./gradlew dependencies --no-daemon" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I build it with this command:
docker build --tag ktdocker .

I use Windows 11 and my goal it to create a Dockerfile so that I can run the application in Google Cloud Run.
Dockerfile
# Use a lightweight Java runtime image
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine as builder

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary tools
RUN apk add --no-cache bash curl git dos2unix

# Copy Gradle wrapper and project files
COPY gradlew ./
COPY gradle ./gradle
COPY build.gradle.kts ./
COPY settings.gradle.kts ./

# Fix line endings and permissions for Gradle wrapper
RUN dos2unix gradlew && chmod +x gradlew

# Download Gradle dependencies
RUN ./gradlew dependencies --no-daemon

# Copy the application source code
COPY src ./src

# Build the application
RUN ./gradlew build --no-daemon

# Use a lightweight Java runtime image for the final build
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the jar file from the build stage
COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/*.jar app.jar

# Expose the application port (Cloud Run uses PORT)
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Main.kt
package com.demo

fun main() {
    val name = "Kotlin"
    println("Hello, " + name + "!")

    for (i in 1..5) {
        println("i = $i")
    }
}

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.20"
}

group = "com.demo"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(20)
}

./gradlew -v
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.8
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2024-05-31 21:46:56 UTC
Revision:     4bd1b3d3fc3f31db5a26eecb416a165b8cc36082

Kotlin:       1.9.22
Groovy:       3.0.21
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          23.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 23.0.1+11-39)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64

What can I change in my Dockerfile so I can build it without errors?
